# What is the best way to test the validity of command line input to script in python?

Tags: python, command-line

When you write a command line program in python, you need to test the validity of the input before doing any computation on it.  What is a best way to do this?

Comment: Based on your code there are many ways!

Comment: There's a module for that: [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python's [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module. It allows you to add options and flags to your script and will allow your script to easily throw an error if an argument is not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is to use a validation function that calls `sys.exit(1)`.  For example, you can do the following:

```
import sys

def usage():
    print("You need 3 arguments")
    print("Usage: script.py arg1 arg2 arg3")
    sys.exit(1)

argc = len(sys.argv)
if argc < 3:
    usage()
# And then with the rest of your script here.
```